# MongoDB monitoring service on local host

Tags: mongodb, performance

Is there a MongoDB server performance monitoring tool which I can run on a local host or a local machine? 
I am concerned about privacy issues while using third-party hosting tools like MongoDB Monitoring Service.

Comment: I hear your privacy concerns. Mostly, 10gen offers the MMS as a way to get your contact information so that they can sell you a support contract.

Answer (score 4):

The MongoDB documentation has information on [Monitoring MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/) including monitoring strategies, relevant [database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/#commands), and some [self-hosted monitoring options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/#self-hosted-monitoring-tools).

If you are concerned about the information collected by MongoDB Cloud Manager (née MMS) or would like to collect this information yourself, you can see a list of [database commands used by the monitoring agent](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/reference/monitoring/).

Comment: It seems that MongoDB Cloud Manager has superseded MMS. The list of commands use by that can be found at https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/reference/monitoring/ Your link is orphaned. If someone were interested in crafting their own monitoring, that list would be a good place to start.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky The original answer was from 2012 so there have been a few changes since then :). I've updated to reflect current links.

Comment: Thank you for updating this. Good answers are eternal! http://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/117471

Answer (score 2):

[MongoBird](http://mongobird.citsoft.net/) is best monitoring tool for MongoDB. It can be installed on all platforms. because it is developed in Java. So, you can install mongobird on the local host.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has created a [free monitoring tool](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring) in version 4.0 which works on localhost. To use it just connect to the database and run `db.enableFreeMonitoring()`

For Example:

```
mongo test
MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

Once you've connected you can enable monitoring like so:

```
test> db.enableFreeMonitoring()
{
 "state": "enabled",
 "message": "To see your monitoring data, navigate to the unique URL below. Anyone you share the URL with will also be able to view this page. You can disable monitoring at any time by running db.disableFreeMonitoring().",
 "url": "https://cloud.mongodb.com/freemonitoring/cluster/HZL3ISL73QLWSNEAYMER2FGR3BINAEGJ",
 "userReminder": "",
 "ok": 1
}
```

Then go to the url provided (`https://cloud.mongodb.com/freemonitoring/...`).

Finally, to disable monitoring:

```
test> db.disableFreeMonitoring()
```